# Regular Expression in python how to find paired words

Tags: python, regex

I'm doing the cipher for python. I'm confused on how to use Regular Expression to find a paired word in a text dictionary.

For example, there is dictionary.txt with many English words in it. I need to find word paired with "th" at the beginning. Like they, them, the, their .....

What kind of Regular Expression should I use to find "th" at the beginning?

Thank you!

Comment: Why use regex at all? Just use `word.startswith('th')`.

Comment: just want to know how to use Regular Expressions,

Answer (score 0):

If you got a list of words (so that every word is a string), you find words beginning with 'th' with this:

```
yourRegEx = re.compile(r'^th\w*') # ^ for beginning of string
```

Answer (score 0):

> ^(th\w*)

gives you all results where the string begins with th . If there is more than one word in the string you will only get the first.

> (^|\s)(th\w*)

wil give you all the words begining with th even if there is more than one word begining with th

Comment: Thanks, what is the difference between re.match and re.compile?

Answer (score 0):

```
(th)\w*
```

notice you have this great online tool to generate python code and test regex:

[REGEX WEBSITE](https://regex101.com/codegen?language=python)